# How to check order of returned records in yaml

Tags: yaml, tavern

Below is the response body of my REST API. I am trying to test this API using Tavern.

```
[
  [
    "ValidOnceAgain", 
    "2019-03-15 00:29:54.579698"
  ], 
  [
    "Comment1", 
    "2019-03-14 21:39:08.016504"
  ]
]
```

My task is to check that these records are returned in order. I am not sure how can I check the order in the YAML file. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to check if your YAML records are sorted by time.

You can convert string with date and time to DateTime object using DateTime.parse(your string).
DateTime objects can be compared. For example `DateTime.parse("2019-03-15 00:29:54.579698")` is bigger than `DateTime.parse("2019-03-14 21:39:08.016504")`
After that you only have to check that `records[i] >= records[i + 1]`